# Python: Find the degree of the Angle [0:360] from cos(a) and sin(a) values

Tags: python, trigonometry

I would like to find the degree between `0` to `360` of my angle.
I have a DataFrame with 2 columns: `cos` and `sin` values.

```
df['cos'] = vector values between 0 and 1

df['sin'] = vector values between 0 and 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I gues you mean something like:

```
import math

angle = math.degrees(math.acos(df['cos']))
```

To really stay in [0, 360] you will have to check for negative cos and adapt the code like:

```
import math
a_acos = math.acos(df['cos'])
if df['sin'] < 0:
   angle = math.degrees(-a_acos) % 360
else: 
   angle = math.degrees(a_acos)
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't mess with sign check.
You need both `cos` and `sin`

```
import math
for i in range(360):
   angle = i * math.pi / 180
   cs = math.cos(angle)
   sn = math.sin(angle)
   angle2 = math.atan2(sn, cs)  # ALWAYS USE THIS
   angle2 *= 180 / math.pi
   if angle2 < 0: angle2 += 360
   print(angle2)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. by the way, `numpy.arctac2()` also works the same way.

Answer (score 3):

The best way of doing this is by using the `np.angle` function which returns the 'angle' associated to a complex number. For a bit of theory, any complex number `z` has a magnitude `r` and an angle `theta`, and is given by

```
z = r*cos(theta) + 1j * r*sin(theta)
```

np.angle takes a complex number as input and returns the angle in radians from $-pi$ to $pi$ (corresponding to -180 to 180 in degrees). Which means that what you're looking for is essentially this

```
angle_negpi_to_pi = np.angle(df['cos'] + 1j*df['sin'])
angle = ((angle_negpi_to_pi + 2*np.pi) % (2*np.pi)) * 180/np.pi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numpy module, which contains trigonometric functions that work on vectors, such as [arcsin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arcsin.html) and [arccos](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arccos.html), which take sin and cos values and return the angle. You can use the [degrees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.degrees.html) function to convert from radians to degrees.